# What are the holomorphic automorphism groups of unit ball, polydisc, and Hartogs domain in C^n ( n>1)?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, automorphism-groups

What are the holomorphic automorphism groups of unit ball, polydisc, and Hartogs domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ ($n>1$) ? I would be pleased if you tell me.

Comment: Have you tried looking them up, in Rudin's books for example?

Comment: @BenMcKay While that might be one of my first impulses, I am not sure everyone should be expected to know in advance of the right places to look. (That said, this question does seem a bit lacking in context or signs of prior effort)

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154612/automorphism-groups-of-unit-disk-mathbfdn-and-unit-ball-bn?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

An excellent reference for the geometry of the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is W. Rudin, **Function Theory in the Unit Ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$**, Springer, 1970. If $B \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is the unit ball, and we pick any $a \in B$, let $P_a$ be the orthogonal projection to the orthogonal complement of $a$ in the standard Hermitian metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $Q_a=I-P_a$. Let $s_a=(1-|a|^2)^{1/2}$. Let $$\phi_a(z)=\frac{a-P_a z - s_a Q_a z}{1-\left<z,a\right>}.$$
Take any $n \times n$ unitary matrix $U$, and finally let $F(z)=U\phi_a(z)$. Then every automorphism of the ball is uniquely expressed as $F$ for some choice of $U$ and $a$, as Rudin proves (in the same notation) on pp. 25-28. Another excellent reference for the geometry in the  ball is W. Goldman, **Complex Hyperbolic Geometry**, Oxford U. Press, 1999.

W. Rudin, **Function Theory in Polydiscs**, Benjamin, 1969, p. 167 proves that every automorphism of any polydisc $\Delta^n$ (with $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$ the open unit disc) is uniquely expressed as the composition of a permutation of the discs and an automorphism of each disk, which is a linear fractional transformation in $SU(1,1)$, as above.

The automorphisms of the Hartogs domains over the classical non-compact Hermitian symmetric spaces are determined in Ahn, Byun and Park, *Automorphisms of the Hartogs type domains over classical symmetric domains*, **Internat. J. Math.** 23 (2012), no. 9. They turn out to be the expected classical Lie groups.